# .NET COM DLL throwing exception when used in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, com, delphi-7

I have a COM DLL produced in C# using VS2010, using it from VS2910, it works fine, but when I try to use the DLL from Delphi 7, having imported the .tlb file, some of the functions work fine, but one seems to generate the following error.
`Could not load file or assembly 'InnovateCV, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c06107b7da48b1da' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
 unfortunatly it have no idea what is failing to load, the InnovateCV is my DLL, and is loaded, getting more information from the exception the Data value is 'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal'. Unfortunally my COM DLL is calling a third party .NET DLL, which is where the exception is being thrown. Is there any way to find what it is failing to load.

I've tried using Depends.exe, and there are no DLL's mising that it can see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any chance that the function it is failing on is a fairly new addition and the delphi code isn't referencing the most recent build of the assembly?

Comment: No there is only set of the DLL's on the system, so the Delphi and C# apps are talking to the same ones. The COM DLL, is re-registered, when I change it to try and debug whats going on.

Comment: You registered the DLL with RegAsm? Is the DLL registered in the GAC?

Comment: Yes the DLL is Register with RegAsm and shows up fine in the Delphi Type Library import wizard, not registered in the GAC, Delphi 7 knows nothing about the GAC.

Comment: Are ALL calls to the third-party-DLL throw this exception or only SOME? The third-party-DLL is in the same directory as your DLL and the Delphi-EXE?

Comment: Only some of the function in the thrid party DLL cause the exception, so it loks like the Thirdparty DLL is loading, but is itself trying to load another DLL. They are not in the same directory as the Delphi-EXE, I will try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, it was a clash of DLL names, between the Delphi App, and the .NET App, so the Delphi App, was failing to find the required function in the DLL, I also had to put all the DLL's in the same directory as the Delphi App. And its now working. Thanks for the Help.